# How to copy text directly to SECONDARY selection in X Windows system in Linux?

Tags: selection, clipboard, x11

I'm trying to create a sort-of "second" copy/paste functionality on my Ubuntu machine. I've read into the different *selections* that the X Windows System has [here](https://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html) and I'm using `xsel` to move code directly into the secondary selection through a keyboard shortcut.

My bash script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set current selection as secondary
xsel -s
```

which should, according to the [man pages](https://helpmanual.io/help/xsel/), operate on the second selection, when I'm highlighting text in another application (e.g. Firefox). But nothing seems to happen. When I replace the `xsel` line with `xsel -p` it operates on the primary selection, no problem. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> which should, according to the man pages, operate on the second selection, when I'm highlighting text in another application.

You didn't understand the manual page correctly:

`-p`, `-s` and `-b` specify which selection is used by `xsel` itself; these switches do not specify which selection is used by other programs.

According to the manual page that you linked, `xsel -p` will **print** the content of the primary selection and `xsel -s` will print the content of the secondary selection.

> But nothing seems to happen.

`xsel -s` will of course not do anything if the secondary selection is empty.

If Firefox does not support the secondary selection, it will not copy anything to the secondary selection, so the secondary selection remains empty.

And according to [a text about the selections](https://sjohannes.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/what-is-the-x11-secondary-selection/), there seem to be nearly no program that supports the secondary selection.

Answer (score 0):

Resurrecting this question a bit late, but `xsel` allows you to 'set' as well as 'retrieve' the selections.

In your case, `xsel -s` will 'retrieve'. To 'set', you need to pass input to the command via standard input, and read it with the `-i` switch (or `-a` if you want to append).

Alternatively, there is a `-x` switch which allows you to exchange primary and secondary selections. It's all in the man page.

In your case, this means you could set one of your shortcuts to `xsel -x` (which will place an existing mouse selection to the secondary selection), and then another shortcut to `xsel -s` to paste that selection into a text buffer/terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I have been experimenting with xsel and xclip and found this question. After experimenting with Tasos answer, using the following commands, the only way to access the secondary buffer is through the xsel -x command.. read on

$ echo "This is for primary" | xsel

The above command will fill up both primary and clipboard buffers

command 2:

$ xsel -x

This command will copy the primary data into secondary buffer

$ xsel -so

Then using the above command will print out the data copied into the secondary buffer. The primary buffer still holds the data, but can be replaced with newer data.